# PanGestureRecognizer selector not called

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

I have a button in an iPad app with `frame.origin.x == 0`. The user has to be able to move the button with his finger. I realized this with a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` and it works fine. However I got a bug report, that the button doesn't move if the user moves his finger from outside the screen (from the black margin of the iPad). I checked and the `selector` of the `UIPanGestureRecognizer` doesn't get called when the touch enters the button's frame. 
Is there any way to fix this? In the iOS main screen it works, so you can scroll the apps even with a gesture started from outside the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I've had a `UIView` outside the screen that came in with that button and it's right-most corner was at `x == 0`. If I set that view to `hidden` when it is outside the screen, the `PanRecognizer` works.